# r grepl and filter dataframe

Tags: r, filter

I am dealing with a dataframe that contains two column with the following values

```
    Col1      Col2
    10        How to; bus; car;
    11        How to;
    12        How to
    13        How to; bus
    14        How to; car
```

What I am trying to do is filter the dataframe such that only rows that contain values like `How to` or `How to;` is retained and rest are discarded. So the final dataframe should look like this below

```
    Col1      Col2
    11        How to;
    12        How to
```

This is what I tried.

```
   filter(df, grepl('How to;|How to', Col2))
```

This is not working, its showing the entire dataframe. Not sure where I am going wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you should try adding an end of line anchor `$` to each of the patterns

Comment: Don't use regex for exact matches. You could just do `filter(df, Col2 == "How to;" | Col2 == "How to")` or not to use dplyr at all and use base R as in `df[with(df, Col2 == "How to;" | Col2 == "How to"), ]` or `subset(df, Col2 == "How to;" | Col2 == "How to")`. Btw, you should always mention the packages you are using

Comment: `df %>% filter(grepl('How to;?$', Col2))` or `df[grepl('How to;?$', df$Col2), ]`

Comment: @alistaire, David, rawr, excellent suggestions thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comments have provided an adequate answer, however, I thought I'd give you an answer more close to your original question.

```
df %>% filter(!(grepl('bus', .$Col2) | grepl('car', .$Col2)))
```

Notice the various differences.  First in your example the or operator `|` appears inside the pattern.  This mean R is literally looking for `'How to;|How to'` not `'How to;'` or `'How to'`.  Second notice how I append `.$` to the column name.  When utilizing `dplyr` the `.` is shorthand for the data you've passed.  Therefore `df$Col2` would have also worked.  You need this because you are passing the argument into a `base` R function and not a `dplyr` function.  Finally, the code `df %>% filter((grepl('How to', .$Col2) | grepl('How to:', .$Col2)))` would not have worked, because `grepl` does not find exact matches.  Rather, it finds instances containing the pattern. You can find exact match, but you need to utilize regex metacharacters. Therefore `df %>% filter((grepl('How to', .$Col2) | grepl('How to:', .$Col2)))` would return the whole data set, i.e. your current output.

Comment: thank Jacob, I will try this too.